# using String.startswith() with a unicode string

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to trim a string scraped from an HTML page using BeautifulSoup.  It starts with

```
&#160;–&#160;
```

in the html page.  I am trying the following code:

```
if thestring.startswith(unichr(160) + '-' + unichr(160)):
    print "found starting sequence"
    thestring= thestring[3:]
```

However, I the `if` condition is not being triggered (as confirmed by the fact that my print statement is not happening).  How do I set up that condition?

(Also in some cases, thestring is initially only those 3 characters, in which case I want thestring to end up as the empty string -- will this do it or will I need to separately test for that case?)

Answer (score 0):

by using `thestring.__repr__()` I was able to determine that what bs was giving me was a string that started with `u'\xa0\u2013\xa0'`

Then the following code works for me:

```
if thestring.startswith(u"\xA0\u2013\xA0"):
    print "found starting sequence"
    thestring = thestring[3:]
```

Comment: note: `u"\xa0" == unichr(160)`. The issue is that `u'–' != '-'` but `u'–' == u'\u2013'`